# Test if I am inside a paired delimiter

Tags: syntax-table, syntax, balanced-parentheses, delimiters

I have been having a problem where I want an `up-sexp` command that treats paired delimiters like `$` in LaTeX-mode just as if they were pairs of balanced parentheses. There are hacks I can use that get me some useful information, but I'd much rather use a built-in command, if one exists.

My problem is that functions like `syntax-ppss` don't care about paired delimiters: for example `(nth 0 syntax-ppss)` returns 0 if I'm in paired delimiters but no parentheses, and there's no special part of the list for paired delimiters like there is for strings. Is there any standard way to get this information?

`sp-up-sexp` and similar commands don't help me, because they also ignore paired delimiters.

Of course, I can write a function to do something like count `$`s in my buffer up to the point, but the problem with this approach is that, for example, `$$` is a separate paired delimiter in LaTeX. It's not a practical problem for me because I never use that notation (it's deprecated and very much not recommended), but I want to get this information from a syntax parser that understands the whole syntax table, not from a hack.

Comment: Warning: it's basically impossible to parse (La)TeX this way.  That's probably why the paired-delimiter "thingy" in syntax-tables is so poorly supported (and completely ignored by `parse-partial-sexp`.  So to stay sane you'll probably want to only count `$` (and `$$`) between point and the nearest "open-like thing" you can find.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. I think that I will use something involving multiple cases and `texmathp` in that case, and just live with weird behavior regarding parentheses.

Comment: Is there a way to convince syntax-ppss that the buffer has changed without actually changing the buffer or seriously messing up its cache? As in, to add hallucinatory braces around math sections. EDIT: I don't think I want to do this, actually.